# How to package and access extra files inside my apk

Tags: android, apk

I have some data files that I need to install together with my application on the emulator for easy testing my app on a device.

Where can I put files in a way that Eclipse will include them into my apk and how can I access those files after my application is installed on the device?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add them to the `res/raw/` folder.

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/resources/resources-i18n.html#ResourcesInCode) to learn how to use it.